# JQuery javascript Galleria IO splice

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullscreen, zk, galleria

i have a galleria using `IO` everything runs smoothly but i have a problem when i try to delete the selected image on the gallery.

here is the code i am using

```
var gallery  = $('#galleriaID').data('galleria');
var index = gallery.getIndex();
gallery.splice(index,1);
gallery.next();
```

everything runs smoothly but when i try to delete the `penultimate` image on the gallery doesn't remove and the gallery is `blocked` in the console i am watching

```
TypeError: data is undefined
version "+version+" to use one or more components.";if(Galleria.version<version...
galler...BC32189 (line 3)
TypeError: self.getData(...) is undefined
```

i am aware is only trying to delete the `penultimate` image int the gallery what i am doing wrong there is some workaround??

thanks a lot...

Answer (score 2):

I've been working through the same issue myself and have a reasonable workaround using `show()` and `setIndex()` that works with `galleria-1.3.js`:

```
var galleria = $('#galleria').data('galleria');
var galleriaLength = galleria.getDataLength();
var currentIndex = galleria.getIndex();
var nextIndex = (currentIndex == galleriaLength - 1) ? 0 : currentIndex + 1;

// Remove the image from the Galleria film slideshow
galleria.splice(currentIndex, 1);

if (galleriaLength > 1) {
  // Need to use show() and setIndex() because next() doesn't work on the
  // penultinate image.
  galleria.show(nextIndex);
  galleria.setIndex((nextIndex == 0) ? 0 : nextIndex - 1);

  // Set a delay of 50ms because there seems to be a race condition
  // of trying to preload images that haven't been spliced out of
  // the gallery yet (working theory).
  galleria.lazyLoadChunks(10, 50);

  // Hack to set the counter because setCounter() isn't working here
  $('.galleria-counter .galleria-current').html(indexToSet + 1);
} else {
  // Destroy Galleria when there are no more images
  galleria.destroy();
}
```

Comment: indexToSet? where is defined